# Adding ASP button into TableCell in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i add a asp button with onclick events in a table cell programatically?

This is what i have tried.

```
TableCell tbBtn = new TableCell();
  Button bt = new Button();
  bt.Text = "Add Books to Database";
  bt.ID = (count++).ToString();
  bt.Click += new EventHandler(btnAddBook);
tbBtn.Controls.Add(bt);
```

But when the page is loaded, the button was a **input type="submit"** and it does not have a onclick event at all.

Here is the view source of the button

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$0" 
    value="Add Books to Database" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_0">
```

How can i make the button to be like an ASP button to runat server and to be able to execute a function when on clicked.

Cheers.

Comment: What you see is correct. A Button does not need an OnClick event. Did you actually click a button to see if `btnAddBook` was triggered?

Comment: I tried to add a breakpoint in btnAddBook but it does not hit, so i was wondering if there is something wrong with the onclick events.

Comment: If you add those buttons to the cell in an IsPostBack check then it wont work. Dynamically added events must be added on each page load, and that includes a PostBack.

Answer (score -1):

You have to differentiate between serverside onClick (runs C# code) and clientside onClick (runs javascript).

If you are talking about clientside then you do it like this - if I remember correctly without VS in front of me :)

```
    Button bt = new Button();
    bt.Attributes.Add("onclick","[your javascript code]";
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: That is what the `OnClientClick` property is for.